# dc.js pagination with data table

Tags: dc.js

First post so apologies in advance if I miss something, just let me know and i'll update what's required.

I'm trying to paginate some data in a data table but it's not displaying correctly.
I get the following:

Data Table NaN:

[image: Data Table NaN]

What I want it to do, is display these are records x - x of x amount of records, on the first page the previous button is disabled. I followed this guide but I can't see where I'm going wrong? Here is my code on GitHub:

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/liam-cafearo/vgs-dashboard/blob/master/static/js/visualization.js)

There are also no errors in the console.

Answer (score 1):

This is now resolved, along with some help from a classmate, I ended up following the guide here [dc.js pagination guide](https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@faad/tutorial-13-dive-into-dc-js-a-javascript-library-data-table-pagination)

Comment: Or you could try [dc.datables.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.datatables.js) - it's brand new but it should have most of the needed basic functionality.